# Using Volley to get list from JSON generating list with last object only

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to fetch data which is in JSON form. but the list created on fetching is having last object details only against every list item. pls guide .

Here is code for Mainactivity to fetch data.

```
package com.example.ankurdell.customlistview;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url

    private static final String url = "https://api.dailymotion.com/videos";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ArrayList<DailyMovie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");


                            DailyMovie movie = new DailyMovie();
                            for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
                                System.out.println("Object Value " + a + " " + obj.toString());

                                movie.setId(obj.getString("id"));

                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));

                                movie.setOwner(obj.getString("owner"));

                                movie.setChannel(obj.getString("channel"));
                                // adding movie to movies array

                                movieList.add(movie);
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        app.AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is DailyMovie class

```
package com.example.ankurdell.customlistview;

/**
 * Created by Ankur Dell on 8/20/2017.
 */

public class DailyMovie {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String channel;
    private String owner;

    public DailyMovie() {

    }

    public DailyMovie(String moviename, String movieid, String theme, String movieowner) {
        this.id = movieid;
        this.title = moviename;
        this.channel = theme;
        this.owner = movieowner;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

can some one advice where I m doing wrong. I referred https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/ to do the coding.

Comment: System.out.println("Object Value " + a + " " + obj.toString());

what's value?

Comment: getting all values perfectly for evry object. ref below  Object Value 0 {"id":"x5xhdeg","title":"Từng đóa bọt sóng _ tập 26","channel":"shortfilms","owner":"x1yzduc"}
08-20 18:59:00.873 26946-26946/com.example.ankurdell.customlistview I/System.out: combine x5xhdegTừng đóa bọt sóng _ tập 26
08-20 18:59:00.873 26946-26946/com.example.ankurdell.customlistview I/System.out: Object Value 1 {"id":"x5xhg83","title":"Bébé Bienvenue Valerie","channel":"tv","owner":"x1pntaq"}

Comment: are you looking for the last JsonObject inside the JsonArray, or the last object inside JsonObject?

Comment: DailyMovie  is just only one element. right?

Comment: @Tony when I hit url, I get list array and it has 4 objects with key-value. I m fetching values for each key and putting them in custom list view. But the list I m getting has only values for last object 10 times

Comment: @Panache please read my answer. you can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DailyMovie is just only one element. right?

You have to declare DailyMovie variable in for statement

```
for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
 JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
 System.out.println("Object Value " + a + " " + obj.toString());

 DailyMovie movie = new DailyMovie();

 movie.setId(obj.getString("id"));                        
 movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));                      
 movie.setOwner(obj.getString("owner"));                                  
 movie.setChannel(obj.getString("channel"));

 // adding movie to movies array
 movieList.add(movie);

}
```